# Avoiding Global Variables with ActionListeners

Tags: java, swing, global-variables, jbutton, actionlistener

So I'm working on a GUI project, and ran into a little problem. I've been getting too comfortable with global variables so I decided to practice working WITHOUT global variables. Here's a simple little project I devised.

Basically, I wanted to be able to create a JFrame with a JButton on it, and on this JButton, there would be a number. Everytime the JButton is pressed, the number goes up by 1. Simple enough, right? Well, I realized that without global variables, I have no idea how to do it. Here's the code with the unnecessary bits removed.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class SOQ
{

   public SOQ()
   {

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SOQ");
      JButton button = new JButton("PRESS HERE");

      programLoop(frame, button);

   }

   public JFrame buildFrame(JFrame frame)
   {

          //unnecessary to include

      return frame;

   }

   public void programLoop(JFrame frame, JButton button)
   {

      int iteration = 1;

      frame = buildFrame(frame);
          //unnecessary to include


      button.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                   //iteration++; //this line returns an error saying the var should be final

                   if(iteration >= 5)
                   {

                      //this is what I want it to reach

                   }

                }

             }

             );

      frame.add(button);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      SOQ mbpps = new SOQ();

   }

}
```

Now, looking at the code, you can see that I am committing a cardinal sin, you can't change values inside the `ActionListener`. So I tried it a few different ways. I tried to put a method in place of `iteration++` that would essentially take in a variable as a parameter, but this turned out to be impossible since the new method can't touch `iteration` since `iteration` is local to a different method, and not global. I even tried messing around with the `ActionListener` and maybe implement it in another class, or extend it in an interface, but neither of those worked out either. Is this is a situation where I HAVE to use a global variable? Because I can't see any other way to do it.

Comment: You've already got a place where you're storing the value: in the text on the button.  You can have your action listener just read the current text, parse it to a number, add 1, and then write the new number back to the button.

Comment: Put it as an answer and you got yourself some bonus points bud

Comment: More specifically, just copy and paste that to an actual answer. I don't need the code, cuz I already know how to. I'm just trying to get you some extra points here

Comment: Your actionListener is an object.  It can have mutable fields.  Its fields can refer to other objects.  Other objects can refer to it.  It can call methods.  There's lots of options open to you.

Comment: Thank you James, azure pointed me to pulling the data off the button, which I guess would be the mutable field you're referring. Just a moment of shit to the brains, I appreciate both of your responses.

Comment: You can also have a final reference to a mutable number type, such as `AtomicInteger`, or use some other sort of "data wrapper" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of ideas, off the top of my head:

```
class MyRandomClass {
    int thisIsNotAGlobal;  //It's an instance variable.
    ...
    void someFoobarMethod(...) {
        JButton button = ...;
        Thingy someThingy = ...;

        button.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    thisIsNotAGlobal++;
                    someThingy.methodWithSideEffects(...);
                }
             });
    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated sir! Azure also mentioned a simpler way of just putting the value on the button itself. I'll stick with that for the moment, but your code is going to cover more options in the future, which was the main thing I wanted to learn through this project. Thanks again!